# Jquery simple accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have simple Jquery accordion, but I have problem of changing header color when tab is opened

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<dl class="accordion-modal">

    <dt><a href=""><header>FIRST</header></a></dt>
            <dd class="active-accordian">FIRST CONTENT</dd>

<dt><a href=""><header>SECOND</header></a></dt>
<dd>SECOND CONTENT</dd>

</dl>
```

**JS**

```
(function($) {

  var allPanels = $('.accordion-modal > dd').hide();
  $('.accordion-modal > .active-accordian').show();

  $('.accordion-modal > dt > a').click(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      $target =  $this.parent().next();

      if(!$target.hasClass('active')){
         allPanels.removeClass('active').slideUp();
         $target.addClass('active').slideDown();
      }

    return false;
  });

})(jQuery);
```

**CSS**

```
header{
    background-color:green;
}

.active{
    background-color:red;
}

.active-header-color{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

What I need when some content is show to add class to that header?
Here is working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/7hLzqoxe/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my fiddle.
refer to it

All you needed to do was add `display:inline-block` to `<a>` element since it is inline element.

https://jsfiddle.net/7hLzqoxe/5/

This was the main part that needed a change

```
  $('.accordion-modal > dt > a').click(function () {
                    $(this).children('header').addClass('green');
$(this).parent().siblings().children('a').children('header').removeClass('green');                        //$(this).parent().siblings().children('a').removeClass('green');
                    allPanels.slideUp();
                    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
                    return false;
                });
```

updated JS Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/7hLzqoxe/6/

Comment: Nice, but i need to add class or remove class  to header, beacuse based on that class in header i have more styling